# Copying Files from external Drive

Tags: files

Hi I have installed Ubuntu 13.04 with single partition. Now I need to copy files from my external drive. What is the possibilities for copying files.

Comment: Plug the drive. Click Drive icon on Launcher. ??? Profit!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via the terminal with the "cp" command

or

You can do it by hand using a file manager like Nautilus which is pre-installed.

or

You can install a file syncronization tool like Synkron

Answer (score 0):

By default, storage devices that are plugged into the system mount automatically in the /media/ directory, open a file browser window for each volume and you can easily copy your files.

If you plug in a usb hard disk with many partitions, all of the partitions will automatically mount.

If the volumes have labels the icons will be named accordingly, otherwise they will be named "disk" and as more volumes are added, you can get "disk-1" and so on.

[image: A graphical file manager in Ubuntu]